# Tcl filename manipulation

Tags: string, tcl

I have a unknown amount of characters in a String e.g.

`C:/Users/test/Desktop/folder/asd.txt`

or

`C:/Users/test/Desktop/newFolder/longtextname.txt`

And I want to trim the end of this string to get only the path and not the file like this:

`C:/Users/test/Desktop/folder/`

I already tried with `string trim` but it doesn't work..

```
 set s1 "C:/Users/test/Desktop/folder/asd.txt"
 set s2 [ string trim $s1 "/*" ]
 puts "<$s1> <$s2>"
```

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
file dirname C:/Users/test/Desktop/folder/asd.txt
```

Documentation: [file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm)